# VBA loop to lookup ref in one worksheet and copy cell data to another

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have two identical workbooks containing identical tables in. One workbook I give to other users to complete their updates in and the other I use as a master copy. The first table column in both workbooks contains a reference number and I want to create a loop that goes through the users workbook matching the reference numbers up to then copy the data in cell in the 8th column for that reference to my workbook. The idea is to avoid manually copying and pasting their updates into my spreadsheet. I've been looking through loop examples but for the life of me can't hook up a way to run the look up and copy paste.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below posted as an answer to another question on here which does the trick :-)

Sub Test1()
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, FR As Long

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

For Each c In w1.Range("B3", w1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    FR = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("B"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("C" & FR).Value = c.Offset(, 1)
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub